# Large scale processing to find unique longest word in very large list of string?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, distributed

I am finding the longest non-repeating string in the input list. Code is [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/39933/find-the-longest-unique-string-in-the-input-list). My question is assume the input list was too huge to fit in memory.

1. How to solve this question if input cannot fit in memory, (ie lets say input is a never ending string of words of a news paper) ?
2. Can / if yes then, how can one use Hadoop/Map reduce concepts (any url's appreciated)

Comment: Are you interested in having an answer that doesn't use Hadoop/map reduce?

Answer (score 3):

If the input is too large to fit in memory, you have two options:

1) Delegate to a database, or some other disk-based structure.  This will be costly in terms of time and resources, but you will get an accurate answer

2) Use a probabilistic method, such as a [Bloom filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter), which is a sort of probabilistic [HashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html).  This would work well with Map Reduce as follows:

Map input `<word>` tuples into `<word, bloom_filter>` tuples, where `word` is the longest word not yet repeated, and `bloom_filter` is the probabilistic representation of all words so far discovered

You can then Reduce two `<word, bloom_filter>` tuples by comparing the two `word` lengths, and checking each one against the other's `bloom_filter`, before combining the two `bloom_filter`s  Note that this may result in there being no longest `word` - this is quite valid, as can be seen in the input case of `(dog, dog, plant, plant)`.

Answer (score 2):

The input list doesn't need to stay in memory: can't you just stream it in?

As far as using MapReduce for this kind of task, take a look at [Data-Intensive Text Processing
with MapReduce](http://lintool.github.io/MapReduceAlgorithms/).